# Magento 2: Checkout Success Page not loading if payment option is cash or wire transfer

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods, checkout-page

I have a strange problem with checkout page. When I choose COD/cash or wire transfer payment and click on "Order" button, order is placed, confirmation e-mail is sent but on the front end nothing happens, only the AJAX icon is spinning.

Console is displaying following error:

> VM80942:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 7
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.process (error-processor.js:28)
>       at Object. (place-order.js:24)
>       at fire (jquery.js:3232)
>       at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.js:3362)
>       at done (jquery.js:9842)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery.js:10311)

and

> "1365"
>   Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: fgets(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length
>   error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong f in /usr/home/domain/domains/domain.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61

If I choose payment gateway, I my case Przelewy24.pl, after payment the Checkout Success Page will display with order number.

Last called URL is https://domain.com/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information POST 200

List of enabled modules:

> Magento_Store
>   Amasty_Base
>   Amasty_InvisibleCaptcha
>   Magento_Directory
>   Magento_Eav
>   DHL_Dhl24pl
>   Magento_Theme
>   Magento_Customer
>   Magento_Backend
>   Magento_Cms
>   Magento_AdminNotification
>   Magento_Indexer
>   Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
>   Magento_Config
>   Magento_Authorization
>   Magento_Catalog
>   Magento_Rule
>   Magento_Backup
>   Magento_Payment
>   Magento_Bundle
>   Magento_BundleImportExport
>   Magento_CacheInvalidate
>   Magento_Quote
>   Magento_SalesSequence
>   Magento_Security
>   Magento_CatalogImportExport
>   Magento_Sales
>   Magento_Cron
>   Magento_Msrp
>   Magento_Search
>   Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
>   Magento_Widget
>   Magento_CatalogInventory
>   Magento_Newsletter
>   Bold_OrderComment
>   Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
>   Magento_User
>   Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
>   Magento_Checkout
>   Magento_ConfigurableProduct
>   Magento_Contact
>   Magento_Cookie
>   Magento_ProductAlert
>   Magento_CurrencySymbol
>   Dialcom_Przelewy
>   Magento_Integration
>   Magento_CustomerImportExport
>   Magento_Deploy
>   Magento_Developer
>   Magento_Downloadable
>   Magento_ImportExport
>   Magefan_Blog
>   Magento_Email
>   Magento_EncryptionKey
>   Magento_GiftMessage
>   Magento_GoogleAdwords
>   Magento_GoogleAnalytics
>   Magento_Ui
>   Magento_GroupedImportExport
>   Magento_GroupedProduct
>   Magento_DownloadableImportExport
>   Adfab_Gdpr
>   Magento_Analytics
>   Magento_LayeredNavigation
>   Magento_MediaStorage
>   Magento_CatalogRule
>   Magento_Multishipping
>   Magento_NewRelicReporting
>   Magento_CheckoutAgreements
>   Magento_OfflinePayments
>   Magento_SalesRule
>   Magento_PageCache
>   Magento_Captcha
>   Magento_Persistent
>   Magento_Reports
>   Magento_ProductVideo
>   Artera_Privacy
>   Magento_QuoteAnalytics
>   Magento_ReleaseNotification
>   Magento_Review
>   Magento_RequireJs
>   Magento_SendFriend
>   Magento_ReviewAnalytics
>   Magento_Robots
>   Magento_Rss
>   Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable
>   Dialcom_ZenCard
>   Magento_SalesAnalytics
>   Magento_SalesInventory
>   Magento_OfflineShipping
>   Magento_Authorizenet
>   Magento_UrlRewrite
>   Magento_CatalogSearch
>   Magento_CustomerAnalytics
>   Magento_Shipping
>   Magento_Wishlist
>   Magento_Sitemap
>   Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
>   Magento_Swagger
>   Magento_Swatches
>   Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation
>   Magento_Tax
>   MagePal_GmailSmtpApp
>   Magento_Translation
>   Magento_GoogleOptimizer
>   Magento_SampleData
>   Magento_CatalogAnalytics
>   Magento_Variable
>   Magento_Webapi
>   Magento_WebapiSecurity
>   Magento_Weee
>   Magento_CatalogWidget
>   Magento_WishlistAnalytics
>   Magmodules_GoogleShopping
>   Phoenix_CashOnDelivery
>   Rakeshmagento_AdvancedShipping
>   Solwin_Contactwidget
>   Temando_Shipping
>   Ves_ImageSlider
>   WebShopApps_Tracker
>   WeltPixel_Backend
>   WeltPixel_GoogleTagManager

List of disabled modules:

> CloudFlare_Plugin
>   Magento_Dhl
>   Magento_Vault
>   Magento_Fedex
>   Magento_InstantPurchase
>   Magento_Marketplace
>   Magento_Paypal
>   Magento_Signifyd
>   Magento_TaxImportExport
>   Magento_Ups
>   Magento_Usps
>   Magento_Braintree
>   Magento_Version
>   Dotdigitalgroup_Email
>   Mirasvit_Profiler
>   Shopial_Facebook

Where should I start looking for possible errors?

Comment: check openssl is enabled on the server or not

Comment: OpenSSL is enabled. Version 1.0.2k-freebsd 26 Jan 2017, Openssl default config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf.